# Where to find a look-up table for mechanical properties of thermoplastics?

Tags: polymers, reference-request, books

Does anybody know of a good compilation, regarding mechanical properties of thermoplastics or in general polymers?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [MatWeb](http://www.matweb.com/index.aspx):

> MatWeb's searchable database of material properties includes data sheets of thermoplastic and thermoset polymers such as ABS, nylon, polycarbonate, polyester, polyethylene and polypropylene; metals such as aluminum, cobalt, copper, lead, magnesium, nickel, steel, superalloys, titanium and zinc alloys; ceramics; plus semiconductors, fibers, and other engineering materials.

There are 84,173 entries in the Polymers tab in the [physical properties search page](http://www.matweb.com/search/PropertySearch.aspx) at the time of my writing this. Note that you can select up to 3 properties at a time to narrow your search (or 10 if you pay for the service: MatWeb is a freemium deal, so be sure to look into whether or not your needs are satisfied by the free/pay versions.)